# How to print serial data into label in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, pyserial

In my code I want to receive serial data to `data` and wanted to print to the label. And wanted to send on/off command by button and selector. Everything is ok except printing the `data` into the label. What will be the next step?

```
import serial
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
win = Tk()
ser = serial.Serial('com8',9600)
def bt1 (): ser.write('on')
def bt2 (): ser.write('off')
def bt3 (): ser.write(v.get())

def makewindow ():
    global v,d
    frame1 = Frame(win)
    frame1.pack(side = LEFT)
    b1 = Button(frame1, text = "ON", command = bt1)
    b2 = Button(frame1, text = "OFF", command = bt2)
    b1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    b2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    frame2 = Frame(win)
    frame2.pack()
    v = StringVar()
    r1 = Radiobutton(frame2,text = 'on', variable = v, value = 'on')
    r2 = Radiobutton(frame2,text = 'off', variable = v, value = 'off')
    r1.select()
    b3 = Button(frame2, text = 'send', command = bt4)
    b3.pack(sid = RIGHT, padx = 5)
    r1.pack(side = LEFT)
    r2.pack(side = LEFT)

    frame3 = Frame(win)
    frame3.pack()
    d = StringVar()
    d.set('default')
    label = Label(frame3, textvariable = d, relief = RAISED)
    label.pack(side = RIGHT)
    return win

def update():
    data = ser.readline(ser.inWaiting())
    win.after(100,update)


update()
win = makewindow()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you be more detailed on your problem? What is not ok with the execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set/get the content of a Tkinter label with `label["text"]`.

Use this snippet:

```
def update():
    global d
    data = ser.readline(ser.inWaiting())
    d.set(data)
```

And please don't use global variables. They are really bad practice. Instead you should wrap you program into a class:

```
import serial
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
class SerialViewer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = Tk()
        self.ser = serial.Serial('com8',9600)

    def bt1 (self):
        self.ser.write('on')

    def bt2 (self):
        self.ser.write('off')

    def bt3 (self):
        self.ser.write(self.v.get())

    def makewindow (self):
        frame1 = Frame(self.win)
        frame1.pack(side = LEFT)
        b1 = Button(frame1, text = "ON", command = self.bt1)
        b2 = Button(frame1, text = "OFF", command = self.bt2)
        b1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        b2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        frame2 = Frame(self.win)
        frame2.pack()
        self.v = StringVar()
        r1 = Radiobutton(frame2,text = 'on', variable = self.v, value = 'on')
        r2 = Radiobutton(frame2,text = 'off', variable = self.v, value = 'off')
        r1.select()
        b3 = Button(frame2, text = 'send', command = self.bt4)
        b3.pack(sid = RIGHT, padx = 5)
        r1.pack(side = LEFT)
        r2.pack(side = LEFT)

        frame3 = Frame(self.win)
        frame3.pack()
        self.d = StringVar()
        self.d.set('default')
        label = Label(frame3, textvariable = self.d, relief = RAISED)
        label.pack(side = RIGHT)

    def update(self):
        data = self.ser.readline(self.ser.inWaiting())
        self.d.set(data)
        self.win.after(100,self.update)

    def run(self):
        self.makewindow()
        self.update()
        self.win.mainloop()

SerialViewer().run()
```

Should work now although I am unable to test it. But where is bt4() defined?

Comment: Actually bt4() will be bt3() and thank you so much 